# Internal Salesforce Error occured when inserting CartItem via Test Class

Tags: unit-test, class, b2b-commerce

Since Monday (May 10, 2021), we've encountered an issue in our test class that we didn't encountered previously. There was a Salesforce update on May 10 so I suspect this was the cause of our issue.

Our issue is that we encountered (Internal Salesforce Error: 681543557-21127 (-1675720177) (-1675720177)) when we try to run one of our Test Classes as **Community Login User** in our UAT sandbox that tries to insert the B2B Commerce object, "CartItem".

Here's the thing, it only happens when running a test class. In the Community Site, creation of CartItem is fine. Running Anonymous in Dev Console is also fine, and running as an Admin gives us no errors.

It's just went our test class tries to insert a CartItem that we get the Internal Saleforce Error above.

Has anyone encountered any similar issues after May 10, 2021? Or perhaps this is an Org issue and it's not really a wide issue?

We've already sent a case to Salesforce Support but they still haven't replied to us back.

Thanks.

Comment: Two things:
1. Are you using the ConnectApi methods or are you doing a straight insert on CartItem via DML?
2. Tag this with b2b and b2b-lightning